# Cannot create subscription using Braintree Payment Nonce

Tags: java, payment-gateway, payment, braintree

I am using a Braintree Payment Nonce to create a recurring subscription request. The below code is what I have to create a subscription. I'm using Payment Nonce which is received from Client. But the subscription request fails with a message "Payment method nonce is invalid."

Any help/pointers would be much appreciated.

```
SubscriptionRequest request = new SubscriptionRequest()
                .paymentMethodNonce(customer.getPaymentNonce())
                .planId(customer.getPlan().getBraintreePlanId());
Result<Subscription> result = getGateway().subscription().create(request);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. I'd suggest you [reach out to our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) if you have more questions.</sub>

Unfortunately the `"Payment method nonce is invalid"` validation error is currently undocumented; that should be fixed soon.

This error means that the nonce couldn't be found, due it not existing, being locked, being already used, not pointing to a vaulted card, etc. In your example, `customer.getPaymentNonce()` likely isn't returning a valid payment method nonce. Make sure it was created with a customer ID and vaulted, and that you're not trying to use the same nonce more than once.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I had figured that out. But thanks very much. I have another Braintree API question which I have posted at the below address. It would be really appreciated if you could take sometime to answer it. Thanks again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148517/braintree-drop-in-ui-does-not-show-cvv-field

Comment: @agf I am still seeing this error message `"Payment method nonce is invalid"`. Any update on this?

Comment: @java_dude You'll have to get in touch with our support team so they can take a look at the specifics of your case.

Comment: @agf I will. Support has been awesome. Thanks.

Comment: @agf sorry to ask different thing , How can we know  that payment done by client is  using Paypal or credit card ?

Comment: @ParagChauhan The payment method nonce you get has a `type` attribute, or equivalent method. See https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/payment-method-nonce/ruby for example.

Comment: In braintree-java-2.63.0 java library, the Customer class does not have a method: "getPaymentNonce"

Comment: @EdJ That is a method on some object the person asking the question created, not on a Braintree object. Once you have a customer with a vaulted payment method, you don't need a nonce -- you can charge the [customer](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/java#customer_id) or [payment method](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/java#payment_method_token) directly.