# Braintree Drop-In UI does not show CVV field

Tags: java, payment-gateway, recurring-billing, braintree

I'm fairly new to Braintree API. I'm using Recurring Payments. And for that I'm using Drop-In UI that is provided by Braintree. Everything goes well but it only shows two fields: Card Number and Expiration Month/Year; and the Paypal button. It's not showing CVV field.

I believe the CVV field is optional and the transaction will still go through if I were to not accept it. But I'm wondering why is it not showing up?

Braintree's new documentation is very limited. And I can't find much info on this problem their website. Any pointers will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you are not seeing the CVV field it means you do not CVV rules configured for your gateway account. You can find more about how to enable CVV rules in the [support documentation](https://support.braintreepayments.com/customer/portal/articles/1430582-avs-and-cvv-recommendations).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

go to Settings -> Processing -> CVV, enable CVV verification rules, and renew the client token.

In this way the CVV field will appear in the Drop-in UI.

Comment: how does one renew the client token?

Comment: Using the [provided API](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+python/sdk/overview/generate-client-token)

Comment: Typically, "renewing the client token" is done automatically if you just refresh the page that the drop-in UI is on.

Comment: CVV options are now under Fraud Prevention

Answer (score 41):

According to Latest Braintree integration there is some change in flow to enable 'cvv' option.

**'CVV'** option will be enable from braintree website.

***Follow this Steps to login into [braintree website](https://www.braintreepayments.com):***

- Go to Settings
- Fraud Management

  - CVV
  - Click on Edit
    - Check option 'CVV not provided(l)'
    - Enable option 'for any transaction'

After this step you can see *'cvv'* option in your app.

Comment: CVV options are now under Fraud Prevention

Comment: Right answer..!!

Answer (score 15):

The CVV now comes under Fraud Management and not in Processing.

[image: Fraud Management Screenshot]

Click on the CVV options and enable it for any transactions.

Comment: This should be the correct answer as they have moved it under Fraud Prevention

Answer (score -4):

This is surely because you are using the sandbox, no?
If you have the cvv activated you can see it when you move go live

Comment: Some banks will accept a payment without one so you need to enable CVV validation